# Normalization constant of blackbody radiation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

We have the Boltzmann-Distribution:  $$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ P_n = N(T) \cdot \exp \left(- \frac {n \cdot h \cdot \omega }{2 \pi \cdot k_B \cdot T }\right) ~~~ , ~n \in \mathbb N_0 ~~~$$   ($n$ = number of photons)

The sum over all the possibilitys $P_n$ must be one.

Now we have to show with the geometric series $ ~\sum_{n=0} ^ \infty x^n = \frac 1 {1-x }   ~~~, |x|<1 ~~~$ that normalization constant is $N(T)=1-\exp\left(-\frac {h \omega }{2\pi \cdot k_B \cdot T}\right) $

What I did:
$~~ \sum P_n = 1 = \sum N(T) \cdot \exp\left(- \frac {n \cdot h \cdot \omega }{2 \pi \cdot k_B \cdot T }\right) = N(T) \cdot \sum \exp\left(- \frac {n \cdot h \cdot \omega }{2 \pi \cdot k_B \cdot T }\right)  $

Now I'm confused, the base of *exp(...)* is *e>1*, so we can't use the geometric series on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your

$$1 = \sum N(T) \cdot exp(- \frac {n \cdot h \cdot \omega }{2 \pi \cdot k_B \cdot T })$$

$$\frac{1}{N(t)} = \sum\ exp(- \frac {n \cdot h \cdot \omega }{2 \pi \cdot k_B \cdot T })$$

Letting $x = exp(- \frac { h \cdot \omega }{2 \pi \cdot k_B \cdot T })$

and using the identity in your question should give the result

$$\frac{1}{N(t)} = \frac{1}{1-exp(-\frac {h \omega }{2\pi \cdot k_B \cdot T})}$$

then do the reciprocal of both sides.

The geometric identity could be used because $e^{-y}= \frac{1}{e^y}$ is less than one for any positive $y$